# Compare semi-circular data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, circular-statistics

I have data on angles between vectors and thus the data lies in the range $[0,\pi]$.
I have two samples of such data, of different sizes. I want some way of quantifying the difference between these distributions.

I appreciate that for fully circular data in the range $[0,2\pi]$ something such as the 
[Watson-Wheeler](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/circular/versions/0.4-93/topics/watson.two.test) test might be applicable.

I also found in the book Statistical Analysis of Circular Data by N.I.Fisher one strategy for analysing data that is not fully circular is to scale it appropriately, analyse, and then back transform to the original scale. That would seem appropriate for calculating a mean for example.

However, I would be sceptical about transforming the data I have to $[0,2\pi]$ to apply a test that yields critical values and a p-value and 'back transform' those results, whatever that means in this instance.

How does one test differences in two angular distributions constrained to $[0,\pi]$?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

These are examples of the distributions, the plots being generated with ggplot/geom_histogram/coord_polar. The question is, are these distributions different?

[image: Plot1]

[image: Plot2]

The distributions look, to me, qualitatively/anecdotally, different. I would like to quantify this somehow.

The means are 92 deg. and 94.4 deg. (applying the formula for a full circular distribution.) These would appear to be not substantially different.

Naively applying the 'watson.two' test to the doubled values yields no significant difference between the doubled distributions. The ECDFs of the original data is
[image: ECDFs]

Now, to me, these look substantially the same.

I am open minded to what metric is used to define "different". It could be mean, median, CDF, ... but would like the metric to be able to discriminate between distributions most effectively. At this stage I am interested in any metric/approach that can be legitimately applied to data in $[0,\pi]$

**FURTHER EDIT**

This briefly describes how the data arise. There are 2 sets of points in 3d space and I have the position vectors of those points relative to a reference point. I analyse the lengths of the vectors in both sets already and this question is about the angles between all pairs of vectors in 1 set and the angles between all pairs of vectors in the 2nd set.

Comment: Usually it's exactly what you think: double the angle.  But whether that's truly appropriate might depend on what you mean by "difference between" distributions and the analysis you want to perform.  It would help to include specific information about those in your question.

Comment: @whuber Pls. see the updated question, and thanks for the input.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use circular statistics at all? As I understand it (but I am far from expert) the "special" thing about circular statistics is that they allow for the fact that the available distribution loops back round to the start (sorry for my terrible terminology!) - i.e. 0 is exactly equivalent to 360. But if you have values from 0-180, this is not an issue, as 180 means something very different from 0. So I would expect you to be able to use a standard test such as Mann-Whitney for the median or (perhaps with a transformation) t-test for the mean.

Comment: @user2390246 It is something I have contemplated. Unfortunately, no, I am not sure ( that I need to use circular stats).

Comment: Tell us more about the measurements. The setup for measurements like this that I know best is whenever there is a line on a map and no reason for record direction on one half of a circle rather than another. So, usually one half is chosen by convention. Are your data like that?

Comment: FWIW, the geometry of these polar plots is all messed up. The scale is linear but sector area is what is seen, and that is proportional to the square of sector length. Much simpler to show conventional histograms!

Comment: @NickCox Pls. see further update. Depends what you mean by "sector area is what is seen". I think these ggplot 'polar histograms' are simply conventional histograms wrapped around so counts are conventional h*w rather than sector area. I could (easily) be wrong and this is worth a follow-up question/test to clarify, elsewhere.

Comment: People reading these polar plots see sector areas being shown. I don't think anything depends on the definitions there: sectors and areas are precisely defined terms.

Comment: @NickCox Putting the visual representation of the data aside, given the additional info asked for, do you have any view on the question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doubling angles first seems quite reasonable here.